# R calculate percentage of unique instances over total sum of different variable

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, percentage, mutate

I have a fairly simple statistical task that I'm having trouble with. I need to calculate the topic that has the greatest and least amount of unique instances. The problem is that the topic was not assigned the same number of times, so I think I need to figure out the number of times the topic referred to a unique instance (`numUnique`) depending on the number of times the topic was coded overall (`numCoded`).

The df looks like this:

| topic | numCoded | numUnique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 63 | 52 |
| B | 134 | 91 |
| C | 19 | 16 |
| D | 35 | 35 |

I tried to calculate the percent change between `numCoded`, but I'm pretty sure that's not what I need to compute and it spits out `NA` for the new column anyway:

```
library(tidyverse)
foo <- propAgree %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (numCoded/lag(numCoded) - 1) * 100)
```

The expected output would look something like this (NOTE: I'm using dummy percentages here because I don't know how to compute this)

```
|      topic     |     similarity    |    
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A         |        30%       |   
|          B         |         50%       |        
|          C        |          70%       |    
|          D         |         20%      |
```

I need to do this for the top and bottom 10 topics, so after calculating the similarity I would then filter for the top and bottom percentage values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: apologies, I switched it to `topic`

Comment: Your input shows only a single row for topic.  Is this the input data on which you are mutating.  If you do grouping on this data, it will be all NA, as lag by default, returns the first row as NA.  Instead, you may want `propAgree %>% mutate(pct_change = (numCoded/lag(numCoded) -1) * 100)`

Comment: yes, but I know that `group_by` refers to multiple rows, I'm just not sure how else to refer to unique instances of `topic`

Comment: You don't need the group_by here.  Can you show your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
prop_Agree %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (numUnique/numCoded) * 100)
```

It will calculate the percentages of numUnique in each topic
Also, if you want them to be ordered, just add

```
%>% arrange(pct_change)
```

in the end and use `head(10)` to extract the bottom 10 and `tail(10)` to extract the top 10

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I need to calculate how similar the unique instances are compared to the amount that the topic is coded over all instances (so maybe something like `mutate(pct_change = (sumUnique/sum(numCoded) * 100)`? But again, this spits out all `NA` values

Comment: So, first try this:
`prop_Agree %>% mutate(numUnique = ifelse(is.na(numUnique),0,numUnique), numCoded = ifelse(is.na(numCoded),0,numCoded)) %>%
mutate(pct_change = (sumUnique/sum(numCoded) * 100)`

Comment: You will replace NA by 0, then it will probably work